# Convergence of sequences problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I am trying to solve this problem .But I am unable to get a method to solve it.
Below is the problem.

If the sequence  $ a_n$ satisfies the property $A =\displaystyle   \lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n$ − $ a_{n-2}$) = 0, prove that $A=\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n$− $ a_{n-1}$)/ n = 0

Please let me know how to solve this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start to a solution. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. By hypothesis here exists an index $N$ with the property that $n \ge N$ implies $|a_n - a_{n-2}| < \epsilon$. Repeated use of the triangle inequality gives $$|a_{N+2}| \le \epsilon + |a_N|, \quad |a_{N+4}| \le 2\epsilon + |a_N|,\quad |a_{N+6}| \le 3\epsilon + |a_N|$$ and so forth. Thus $|a_{N+2k}| \le k\epsilon + |a_N|$ for all $k \ge 1$.  For the same reason you can conclude that $|a_{N+2k - 1}| \le k \epsilon + |a_{N-1}|$ for all $k \ge 1$.  Consequently $$|a_{N + 2k} - a_{N+2k-1}| \le 2k \epsilon + |a_N| + |a_{N-1}|,\quad k \ge 1,$$ and thus $$\frac{|a_{N + 2k} - a_{N+2k-1}|}{N+2k} \le \epsilon + \frac{|a_N| + |a_{N-1}|}{2k},\quad k \ge 1.$$ What happens as $k \to \infty$?